# How to keep the currentPage variable after clicking on the detail link Using Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am starting with vue.js, the code below is fine, the idea is when a person clicks in detail, I send it to another component to see the detail of the user this is fine, what I need is when the user clicks on it link back inside the detail component, keep the currentPage variable, what it does is set the currentPage variable to 1

I found something called keepAlive, but I really don't know how it works.

Also some way for mounted to run once.

```
this is my view here i call the Users component
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Lista de Usuarios</h1>
        <Users/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Users from "@/components/Users.vue";

export default {
    name:"Usuarios",
    components:{
       Users 
    }
};
</script>
```

```
Users component
<template>
    <div id="ejemplo">  

      <b-table
      id="tabla"
      :items="usuarios"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      :fields="fields"
      small
    >

      <template v-slot:cell(Detalle)="fila">
        <b-link :to="{ name: 'Usuario', params: { id:fila.item.id} }">Ver Más</b-link>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:cell(Elimina)="fila">
        <b-button size="sm" @click="elimina(fila.item.id)" class="mr-2">
          Elimina</b-button >
      </template>


     </b-table>

    <b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="total"
      :per-page="perPage"
      aria-controls="tabla"
    ></b-pagination>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"Users",
    data(){
        return{
            perPage: 3,
            currentPage: 1,
            usuarios:[],
            fields: ['id', 'name', 'Detalle','Elimina'],
            total:0,
        }
    },
    methods:{
       async Listar(){
        let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        let data= await response.json()
        this.usuarios= await data
        this.total= await this.rows()
        },
       rows() {
        return this.usuarios.length
       },
      elimina(id){
        this.usuarios=this.usuarios.filter(usuario=>usuario.id !== id)
      }


    },  

     mounted(){
        this.Listar()
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your case it makes sense to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/). Vuex is something like a a globally store for your Vue-Application. You could set the "currentPage"-Variable in there and change it's value by using "mutations".